# Question About a Non-Decreasing Sequence

Tags: calculus, analysis

can you tell me what is the purpose of -1/n there? As far as I understand the a2n and all other elements of the sequence is equal to 1. So also how's an going different values on the graph?

[image: the sequence]

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  It's just an example of a sequence, we can't really guess the purpose of writing down this particular one without knowing the author's mind.

Comment: Another way of writing the sequence would be $a_n = 1 - 1/(n/2)$ for $n$ even, and $a_n = 1 - 1/((n-1)/2)$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: I am not asking the purpose though, sorry if my question was bad explained. My question is about the -1/n, because I couldn't understand how to read it in the process.

And my second question is about the graph. I couldn't understand how such sequence would print a graph like this?

Comment: You can generate it yourself: for example, for $n=3$ you have $a_{2n} = 1 - 1/n = 1-1/3 = 2/3$. So $a_6 = 2/3$. That corresponds to the point $(6, .6666\ldots)$ on the graph.

Comment: Maybe you're confused by the syntax/spacing on the formula. $1/n$ is being subtracted from $1$.

Comment: Yes, that spacing confused me. Thank you for the explanation.

And one more question just to be clear,
Let's say that n=3. a6 would be equal to a7, right? Or whatever value we give to n, it'll just be equal to it's next value. Because the formula says a2n = a2n+1.

Comment: Yes, each even term is equal to the following odd term, so $a_6 = a_7$, $a_8 = a_9$, and so on.

Comment: Glad you got unstuck. The spacing does look slightly wrong. Cheers